# Examples of Berkeley DB usage within SWI-Prolog

Tags: swi-prolog, berkeley-db

Can anyone point to examples of using SWI-Prolog's Berkeley DB interface to persist typical Prolog facts?

Comment: It would also help having some SICStus Prolog examples. SICStus and SWI-prolog differ quite a lot on the way they interface with Berkeley DB.